# MongoDB database only shows when mongod is on

Tags: mongodb

I only can see a database in Robo 3T after I've ran mongod in terminal.

I'm trying to export a database with mongodump, but I'm unable to see the database.

It has a collection within it, but I can only see it when it's running on the default port; if I turn off the port, it's no longer visible in Robo 3T.

Edit:
My question is, how can i do a monodump from this?
Edit:
I can never see the database in the mongo shell, even when mongod is turned on

Comment: Yes. That's how database servers work. It must be running in order to access it. Much earlier releases of MongoDB included "offline access" for tools such as `mongodump` which would simply work with the files in the filesystem directly. This is no longer the case. `mongod` is meant to be running all the time.

Comment: how can i do a dump from this?

Comment: By running `mongod`, just like I said. The process must be running in order for any other tools/programs to access it.

Comment: even while it's running, i cannot do a dump or see the database

Comment: *"f I turn off the port, it's no longer visible in Robo 3T"* - Your words. It implies MongoDB is not in fact running. You might try being more explicit in your question. Show the actual steps ( no pictures please, text will do ) which you are performing in order to run MongoDB and then subsequently then attempting `mongodump`.

Comment: Correct. I meant to say in my last comment that i can never see the database from terminal when i go into mongo shell and use db

Comment: You need to edit your question and demonstrate exactly what steps you have taken just like I already said. Without that, it's extremely unclear and likely to be closed.

Comment: As pointed out by others DB has to be running in order to do any operation or just to see the database.   
1. First run mongod
2. go to new cmd prompt and then run mongodump with all necessary option and  database you want to dump or just a collection if you want to dump single collection.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you follow the following points after opening the terminal:

- Start mongod : `sudo service mongod start`
- check mongod status : `sudo service mongod status`   (should show as running)
- Goto mongo portal : `mongo`
- See all databases : `show dbs`
- See all collections : `show collections`
- Goto specific database : `use dbName`
- check all collections : `show collections`
- If all seems fine, exit the portal : `exit`
- Goto the path where you want the dbDump  `cd path`
- Take mongoDump : `mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 --port portNumber -d dbName`  (usually default mongo port is 27017)

If you are still facing any issues, please comment with the screenshot of output of each of the command above